# How to return the response Body of the server response instead of Nginx defaulte Error page

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-unit

I have a api route which clients can call, lets call it `/test`
Now in that `/test` route, i want to call `/auth` route to verify the authentication part, In side the `/auth/` block there's a another auth api called, `http://app:5000/give_401` which returns
either 1. `401` and JSON response
or 2. `200` and json response
If the response code is `401`, then whatever json response is recieved, same has to be sent to the client, else, it can follow the normal path.
Here is my `nginx.conf` file.

Thanks in advance.

```
events {
    worker_connections 1000;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location /auth/ {
          proxy_pass http://app:5000/give_401;
        }

        location /test {
            auth_request /auth/;
            proxy_pass http://app:5000/ok;

        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and  business environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: Hey Buddy, feedback is much appreciated, I have corrected the question, hope it helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485557/1016033 It's impossible with auth_request.

Comment: The relevant setting should be [`proxy_intercept_errors`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors), which defaults to `off`. In my tests with a pretty default configuration I receive the JSON from the backend server on the client.

Comment: where should i put this setting? It is not working in either of the blocks

Comment: I Could not find a solution, I just ended up using 2 solutions,  

1.  `access_by_lua_block`  instead of using auth request, I just used a lua script for making a authentication request and reading its response code, and use ngx.say for responding the body back.
2. just override the default 401 and call auth route again in it: 

`
        error_page 401 =401 /auth_failed_401; 

        location /auth_failed_401 {
            proxy_pass http://backend_api/give_401_h;
        }   

`